# How to suppress blank space before a value

Tags: r

```
Country<-c(" Germany"," France", "Greece"," United-State", "Spain")
Country
```

There are blank spaces for example before `Germany`, `France` and `United-State`

```
[1] " Germany"      " France"       "Greece"        " United-State" "Spain"
```

I want to suppress all the the blank spaces before the country names, in order to have some like this:

```
[1] "Germany"      "France"       "Greece"        "United-State" "Spain"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `str_trim` from the `stringr` package in order to remove whitespace from the start and end of a string.

**Code:**

```r
library(stringr)

Country<-c(" Germany"," France", "Greece"," United-State", "Spain")

str_trim(Country)
```

**Output:**

```
[1] "Germany"      "France"       "Greece"       "United-State" "Spain"
```

**Original:**

```
[1] " Germany"      " France"       "Greece"        " United-State" "Spain"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

We can use `trimws` from `base R` (no packages used)

```
Country <- trimws(Country)
Country
#[1] "Germany"      "France"       "Greece"       "United-State" "Spain"
```

---

Or with `sub`

```
sub("^\\s+", "", Country)
```